# Максимальное число правок для вопроса и ответа

Tags: поддержка, предложение, правки

1. Сколько раз я могу редактировать свой вопрос\ответ ?
2. Сколько раз я могу редактировать чужой вопрос\ответ ?

   > У вас слишком много правок, ожидающих проверки. Новые правки не могут быть предложены, пока предыдущие не будут утверждены.

Ограничения всё же **есть** для простых смертных.6 правок и такое предупреждение. Может на 50 правках чтобы такое высвечивалось?

3. Почему существует такое ограничение? Чтобы работы для модерации было меньше или защита от ботов редакторов?

Comment: А при чём здесь метка [meta-tag:предложение]?

Comment: Может на 50 правках чтобы такое высвечивалось? Если нет, то окей, уберу.

Answer (score 5):

Насколько мне известно, количество редакций для сообщений не ограничено. Неважно ваше это сообщение или нет.

Если ваша репутация не позволяет вносить правки без утверждения другими участниками, то прежде чем предлагать новые может потребоваться подождать утверждения старых. Однако к исходному вопросу о количестве редакций это имеет косвенное отношение. Так как редакция — это уже утвержденная правка.

Очередь введена, чтобы лучше контролировать нового участника, так как он может еще не знать нюансов того, какие правки полезны, а какие нет. Будет не очень хорошо, если он наплодит уйму предложенных правок, которые придется отклонить. Это пустая трата как времени проверяющих, так и времени самого новичка.

Кстати, очередь предложенных правок не только на отдельного участника распространяется, но есть еще и [общее число на сайт](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/345125/3240681).

Comment: Уже нет такого, сообщения не становятся общими.

Comment: Вот в ответе 24 ревизии, но общим он не стал. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/431840/revisions

Comment: @NickVolynkin, это потому что автор редактировал

Comment: @NickVolynkin странно, где-то я точно об этом читал. Хотя судя по [правке](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/11741/40) приведение к «общему» отменили еще в 14 году.

Comment: @Grundy [отменили](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/228947/339911), действительно.

Comment: Если не ограничено, то с какой стати вопрос от pepsicoca вчера закрыли с формулировкой "слишком много правок"?

Comment: @VadimTagil уже открыли обратно. Там не в правках проблема .

Comment: @VadimTagil то, что количество правок не ограничено технически, не значит, что следует стремиться к этой бесконечности и видоизменять, перерабатывать вопрос на каждый данный комментарий. Хочется расширенного диалога — идите в [chat]. Вопросы же должны быть четкими и хорошо проработанными, где можно легко выделить суть, чтобы получить такой же четкий ответ.